# Where clause magic in MySQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I've found something in MySQL which astonished me a lot. I created a table and inserted records into it as below,

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
   `ID` int,
   `NAME` varchar(100)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');
```

Now, I run two SELECT queries against this as below,

```
select * from test where id;

select * from test where name;
```

I noticed these queries do not throw syntax errors but the "**first**" select query returns result as 
`select * from test;` 
while the "**second**" one doesn't return any. This means if the where clause contains an "**integer**" column I get a result set, while I don't get any if where clause contains a "**varchar**" column.

Can anyone tell me whether this is a bug or a feature in MySQL? Also explain me why this happens.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want? Do you mean `SELECT id FROM test` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In MySQL `0` is `false` and `not 0` is `true`. So

`where id` for instance is like `where 1`.

So your `id`s are all `true` and return the record.

But `name` can't be automatically converted to a `not 0` number and is `false`.

BTW if the `name` column value would start with a number, then it would be converted to that number and be  `true` (for instance `1tom` would return in `1`).

Comment: Hi,why does this not happen for varchar columns?

Comment: Because a string that does not start with a number will be converted to the number `0` to make the boolean comparison

Answer (score 1):

`name` columns are converted to `0` because they are not `numerical format`. It could be fetched if name is '2' with warnings.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, name VARCHAR(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test VALUES (0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, '2');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE name;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    2 | 2    |
+------+------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'a' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'b' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```